# How to go down to different sections in the same page and go all the way up using buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am fairly new to javascript. I am stuck on this code.
I'm trying to create a button to navigate between top and bottom of a web page. Initially, the *scroll to bottom* works, but once I click on the *back to top* button, the scroll down logic breaks. I'm unable to figure out where I'm applying the incorrect logic. Thanks in advance

https://jsfiddle.net/riodahamster/9vtxh0aL/9/

```
var i = 1;
$(".scroll-top").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");
  window.icount = 0;
});



var icount = 0
$('.down-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.icount++;
  var offset = $("div.next-section").eq(icount).offset().top;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 400);

});
```

Comment: Does not seem to be breaking... Must be something else. https://jsfiddle.net/6fthm7ur/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Scroll Into an element using vanilla JavaScript. Just follow the tricks.

The [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) scroll the page to view the element. For that purpose here I've created two empty elements `#top-view` and `#bottom-view` at the top and the bottom of the HTML respectively.

After that when you click on `Go Bottom` and `Go Up` buttons then it brings you to the `#bottom-view` and `#top-view` elements.

```js
const bottomBtn = document.querySelector('#go-bottom');
const upBtn = document.querySelector('#go-up');
const topView = document.querySelector('#top-view');
const bottomView = document.querySelector('#bottom-view');

bottomBtn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    bottomView.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});

upBtn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    topView.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});
```

```css
#page-1 {
    background: yellow;
    color: #222;
}

#page-2 {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- empty element for scrolling into it -->
<div id="top-view"></div>
<button id="go-bottom">Go Bottom</button>
<section id="page-1">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem esse cupiditate unde magni facilis, quod saepe ad eligendi tenetur voluptas ea maxime dolorem id explicabo incidunt tempora quae debitis soluta!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, voluptatum aspernatur aut explicabo dignissimos aperiam, ut exercitationem labore? Hic necessitatibus nostrum delectus suscipit nihil eveniet asperiores alias facere a quod.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem esse cupiditate unde magni facilis, quod saepe ad eligendi tenetur voluptas ea maxime dolorem id explicabo incidunt tempora quae debitis soluta!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, voluptatum aspernatur aut explicabo dignissimos aperiam, ut exercitationem labore? Hic necessitatibus nostrum delectus suscipit nihil eveniet asperiores alias facere a quod.
    </p>
</section>

<section id="page-2">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem esse cupiditate unde magni facilis, quod saepe ad eligendi tenetur voluptas ea maxime dolorem id explicabo incidunt tempora quae debitis soluta!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, voluptatum aspernatur aut explicabo dignissimos aperiam, ut exercitationem labore? Hic necessitatibus nostrum delectus suscipit nihil eveniet asperiores alias facere a quod.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem esse cupiditate unde magni facilis, quod saepe ad eligendi tenetur voluptas ea maxime dolorem id explicabo incidunt tempora quae debitis soluta!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, voluptatum aspernatur aut explicabo dignissimos aperiam, ut exercitationem labore? Hic necessitatibus nostrum delectus suscipit nihil eveniet asperiores alias facere a quod.
    </p>
</section>
<button id="go-up">Go Up</button>

<!-- empty element for scrolling into it -->
<div id="bottom-view"></div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So i am trying to make this button to be dynamic. I am trying to go down to multiple sections in the page.      icount++;
   var offset = $("div.next-section").eq(icount).offset().top;
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
  scrollTop: offset
   }, 400);

Comment: Please study scrollIntoView a little bit. You can scroll into any element by this. You can do document.querySelector('#page-' + count).scrollIntoView();

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine. The issue is you havent added Jquery!

[image]

Also you have to target the bottom div to get the down function to move you to the bottom of the page. In this case, yello class div!

```
var i = 1;
$(".scroll-top").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");
  window.icount = 0;
});



var icount = 0
$('.down-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.icount++;
  var offset = $("div.next-section.yellow").eq(icount).offset().top;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 400);

});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/riodahamster/9vtxh0aL/20/     I added jquery. But page is not moving down after page moves to the top.